# MySQL Teamwork (data modeling)

Tags: mysql, database-design, version-control, collaboration

How do you organize modeling (large) MySQL databases in a team? In the past I was used to using MySQL Workbench to model the database, then generate an incremental sql script which was commited to git/svn. I'm having a hard time convincing my new team to work like this and honestly it would be nicer to have some team features in MySQL workbench or Navicat MySQL. For example to be able to sync your own model with a central model which is the master. I guess you could setup something like this manually.

How do you organize your team when it comes to data modelling?